# Spring Ignore field just in getAll method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of persons in DB everyone having a CV field which is a MultiPart File in Spring. I'm trying to get all persons from db, but to ignore the CV field because I don't want to be downloaded when I use getAllPersons function. I saw a possibility with JsonIgnore but I want to ignore that field just in getAllPersons, not in other functions like getPersonById etc. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you can use HQL.

i.e

```
interface Repo extends C... {
     @Query(select h.name, h.phone, ... from Person h)
     List<Person> getAllPerson();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you use `Sping` and `Spring-data` you can use a projection in order to avoid maintaining custom queries. Consider the following example:

1. Entity class `Book`

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "book_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "book_sequence", sequenceName = "book_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    private String author;

    private String publisher;

    private String plot;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Set<BookFilter> filters = new HashSet<>();

}
```

2. Projection interface:

```
public interface BookNameAuthorOnly {

    String getName();
    String getAuthor();

}
```

3. Repository method:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    List<BookNameAuthorOnly> findBy();

}
```

When the latter is invoked, the dynamic query generated by Spring, will select only the fields that you have specified in the related `interface` object. For more on this you can check the following documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Don't know if this fits your use case scenario but this is also another way of achieving what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DTO` as shown in below example:

Person entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    @Lob
    private Object cvFields;
}
```

PersonDTO:

```
package com.example.dto;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonDTO {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public PersonDTO(Person person) {
        this.id = person.getId();
        this.name = person.getName();
        this.address = person.getAddress();
    }
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT new com.example.dto.PersonDTO(p) FROM Person p")
    List<PersonDTO> getAll();
}
```